# Good vs Bad Trial in Probability

Tags: probability, self-study

I am watching [this video](https://youtu.be/GDVZ-O_EXMY) on Probability, around the end there is a problem to be solved:

[image]

I can't understand how a summation which extends from 1 to infinity can be equal to  $\frac{1}{1-4/6}$

Comment: Search Geometric series on internet.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula -- it even shows how to derive it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series $S = (\frac 46)^0\frac 16 +(\frac 46)^1\frac 16+... = ar^0 +ar^1 + ar^2...$ is a geometric series. You can search Geometric Series on internet to get the answer. In addition, you may get the result for the sum of the first n terms of a geometric series, which is $a \frac {1-r^n}{1-r}$ and also useful in statistics.

Answer (score 2):

You know the sum is finite, since it is a probability and so must be between $0$ and $1$.  Let's call it $S$ where $$S=\frac16+\left(\frac46\right)\frac16 +\left(\frac46\right)^2\frac16 +\left(\frac46\right)^3\frac16 +\cdots$$

Multiplying through by $\frac46$ gives $$\frac46 S=\left(\frac46\right)\frac16 +\left(\frac46\right)^2\frac16 +\left(\frac46\right)^3\frac16+\left(\frac46\right)^4\frac16 +\cdots$$

and taking the difference gives $\dfrac26 S=\dfrac16$ i.e. $S=\dfrac12$, as you might intuitively expect from the symmetry in the question.  This is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)